# Repeated occurrence of C2275 Error

Tags: c

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 on Windowns 7. For some un-understandable reason i keep getting the C2275 error when i try to compile the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

typedef struct list_node   
{  
   int x;   
   struct list_node *next;  
}node;  

node* uniq(int *a, unsigned alen)   
{  
   if (alen == 0)   
          return NULL;    
   node *start = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));   //this is where i keep getting the error   
   if (start == NULL)   
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);    
   start->x = a[0];    
   start->next = NULL;     
   for (int i = 1 ; i < alen ; ++i)   
   {
          node *n = start;  
          for (;; n = n->next)  
          {  
                 if (a[i] == n->x) break;  
                 if (n->next == NULL)   
                 {  
                       n->next = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));  
                       n = n->next;  
                       if (n == NULL)   
                              exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  
                       n->x = a[i];   
                       n->next = NULL;  
                       break;  
                 }  
          }  
   }  
   return start;  
}  

int main(void)  
{
   int a[] = {1, 2, 1, 4, 5, 2, 15, 1, 3, 4};  
   /*code for printing unique entries from the above array*/  
   for (node *n = uniq(a, 10) ; n != NULL ; n = n->next)  
          printf("%d ", n->x);    puts("");    
   return 0;  
}
```

I keep getting this error "C2275: 'node' : illegal   use of this type as an expression" when i compile. However, i asked one of my friends to paste the same code in his IDE it compiles on his system!!
  I would like to understand why the behaviour of the compiler is different on different systems and what influences this difference in behavior.

Comment: Is it indeed `**node *start` in your code? That's ill-formed.

Comment: also, add comments to the code as comments.

Comment: Are you compiling as C++? The `for` loop in `main` uses a variable of type `list_node` ... but that type does not exist in C: in C there exists a type `struct list_node` which is also typedef to `node`. Compile as C, crank up your compiler warning levels, and **mind the warnings!!**

Comment: no i am compiling this as a C code and thanks for pointing out the other typo..well it turns out that C does not like it we do not declare variables before we start work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't declare a variable `node * start` after other code statements. All declarations have to be at the start of the block.

So your code should read:

```
node * start;

if (alen == 0) 
    return;

start = malloc(sizeof(*start));
```

Comment: Does VS 2010 conform to C99? I didn't think it did by default. And that error (C2275) is what you get when you declare a variable when it wasn't expecting you to.

Comment: That declaration trick did the job!! Thanks Vicky!! i guess working in C++ has spoilt me...

Comment: @Vicky: No, Visual Studio does not support C99, and AFAIK MS has no plans to do so.

Comment: @vicky: shouldnt the last line be start = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node)).

Comment: `sizeof(node)` and `sizeof(* start)` are the same thing (I prefer `sizeof(* start)` because it means if you change the type of `start` you only have to change the declaration. As for the cast, yes I think VS2010 does warn if you don't explicitly cast the result of `malloc()` to the type you are assigning to.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you have `**node` there.

You simply need `node *start`;

Comment: That is a formatting mistake..sorry about that..this was my first post on stack overflow...this is how it was supposed to look  
    node *start = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));     
i am not able to figure out how to get the asterix sign..